# SUM all fields in an column, except for n specified range

Tags: excel

I want to sum the values of column B where column A does not contain specified fields or blank fields. I have tried the following, but does not work

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNA(MATCH(B:B,{"ASY999","ASY002","CIB001"},0))*(G:G<>""))-1
```

I need to reference an entire column, for future expansion on the data. Here is my sample data that i am trying to conditionally sum in EXCEL 2007.

```
**A      B**
        5.00
        2.00
        2.00
        2.00
ASY999  1.00
AFS001  4.00
ASY002  5.00
AFS001  5.00
CIB001  2.00
```

Comment: could you please show desired output... is it AFS001 will be there in column C and in column D sum would be 9?? For ASY999, it will be 1, for ASY002 it will be 5 and so on???

Comment: both below queries give me answer 9, but I don't get what that 9 means....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the formulas already given for backward compatibility you could use:

`=SUM(B:B,-SUMIF(A:A,{"ASY999","ASY002","CIB001",""},B:B))`

If you're considering future expansion of data, I'd suggest using the Table feature on the insert Tab in Excel 2007 instead of referring to full columns.

Comment: The question is looking to find the sum of values in column B where column A does not match any of a list of specified criteria. In this case the only values in column A that do not match the criteria {"ASY999", "ASY002", "CIB001", ""} are those that contain "AFS001" and the sum of the corresponding values in column B is 9. At least that's my interpretation

Comment: that means if the A is duplicate, he need sum of those... suppose there is one more row as `ASY002 5.00`, then answer would be 19 (4+5+5+5)... right??? **Also** while replying could you add @Fahim Parkar so that I will get notification in Inbox??

Answer (score 1):

Try this with `SUMPRODUCT` as shown below

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNA(MATCH(A:A,{"ASY999","ASY002","CIB001"},0))*(A:A<>""),B:B)
```

although `SUMIFS` should be better for a small number of excluded values, it's faster.

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,"<>ASY999",A:A,"<>ASY002",A:A,"<>CIB001",A:A,"<>")
```

Comment: Jean-Pierre wants to sum column B where column A is not any of the 3 specified values or blank, hence the answer is 9 because the only two rows that should be summed given those criteria are the rows conatining AFS001, so 4+5 = 9

Comment: that means if the A is duplicate, he need sum of those... suppose there is one more row as `ASY002 5.00`, then answer would be 19 (4+5+5+5)... right???

Comment: No, I don't think that's right, ASY002 is one of the "excluded values" - result should still be 9